# how to read a json received in an apex class

Tags: apex, json

I am new to the APEX programming language. I have a json string that contains an input and output and I need to read the json as input of an apex class and do manipulations on the file to display the output result from a comparison between the json file variables with personale fields in salesforce but I found two problems. please can you help me. thank you in advance.

```
public static void CalValues ​​(Map<String,Object> Input, Map<String,object> Output) {

    // String Input= '{"orderScor": { "offer": "","commitment": 0,"Addition":
    [{"Code": "","Value":"" }]}} ';
    Map<String, Object> deserialize = (Map<String,
    Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(json.serialize(input));
    Map<String, Object> orderScor = (Map<String, Object>)
    deserialize. get('orderScor');
    Map<String, Object> offer = (Map<String, Object>)
    orderScor. get('offer');
    List<Map<String,Object>>Addition=
    (List<Map<String,Object>>) orderScor.get('Additione');
    Map<String, Object> i = new Map<String, Object> ();
             
    for (Object x: Addition) {
        i = (Map<String, Object>) x;
    }
    Map<String, object> Code = ( Map<String,
    Object>)i.get('Code');
    system.debug(deserialize);
    List<MOUNT__c> orderScorRe = [Select cal__c,val__c from MONT__c
                                 where (offer= :offer)];/*Invalid bind
    expression type of Map<String,APEX_OBJECT> for column of type
    String**
    Output = json.serialize(orderScorRe);/*Illegal assignment from String to
    Map<String,Object>*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, you're telling the compiler that `offer` is a map, but from your JSON It looks like it should be a String:

```
Map<String, Object> offer = (Map<String, Object>) orderScor. get('offer');
```

should be:

```
String offer = (String) orderScor. get('offer');
```

Then your binding will work because a String can be used as a binding value in a query.

Your second issue is also type based (making me think you're coming from JS or another typed language).

`Output` is defined in the parameters as a `Map<String, Object>` but given that you're serializing an object, you're generating a String:

```
Output = json.serialize(orderScorRe);
```

... and these two types are not compatible. I'm guessing you either want your function to return a String, or if you really want to populate `Output` with the type it has you'll need to serialize, and then deserialize to Output:

```
Output = (Map<String, Object>)json.deserializeUntyped(json.serialize(orderScorRe));
```

Comment: Output = json.deserializeUntyped(json.serialize(orderScorRe));  l changed but still.the same error   Illegal assignment from Object to Map<String,Object>

Comment: Oh you'll need to cast the output still - deserializeUntyped() always returns a generic object. I'll update the last code sample now